# I scrape data with bs4 I want to end the loop after last value found

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, while-loop

I don't know how much usernames have because in each iteration data change old users are replaced with new ones so I don`t know who will be the last.How can I break the loop after no more new users are found.

```
n = 0

usernames = soup.find_all('div', class_='KV-D4')
while n < 10000:
    for each in usernames:
        each.get_text()
        n+=1
        if(usernames[last]):
            break
```

Comment: Hello, could you show us the html being scraped. Thank you

Comment: Where is `n` being set?

Comment: Its have only repeted classes and id no area-lebal or something witch I can fetch

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is loop through a list of divs and break as soon as the value are no longer unique; then create a list and add items that are not unique otherwise break.

**For example:**

```
unique_usernames = []

usernames = soup.find_all('div', class_='KV-D4')
for each in usernames:
    username = each.text
    if username in unique _usernames:
        break # First not unique user found
    else:
        unique_usernames.append(username)
```

Comment: I need the wile loop its do some actions after the for loop

Comment: I left out the while loop as I felt it was not relevant for the minimal reproducible https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. By all means add it to your solution, if you need it. Did my answer fix your problem?